# Picard Lindelöf Theorem with missing domain of $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

In my lecture we introduced the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem the following way.

> **Theorem (Picard-Lindelöf)**: Let $f(t,y)$ be continuous on a cylinder
>
> $$D = \{(t,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d | |t-t_0| \leq a, |y-u_0| \leq b\}$$
>   Let $f$ be bounded and satisfy a Lipschitz condition in its second argument. Then the IVP
>   $$u' = f(t,u)\hspace{15pt}u(t_0) = u_0$$
>   is uniquely solvable on the interval $I = [t_0 - T, t_0 + T]$ for some $T> 0$

Now I'm looking at the following IVP:

$$u'(t) = u(t)^\frac{1}{4}\hspace{5pt}\forall t \geq 0\hspace{30pt}u(0) = 0$$

I'm asked to give to different solutions to the IVP and show that $f(x) = x^\frac{1}{4}$ is Lipschitz-continuous on every interval $[\epsilon, \infty)$ with $\epsilon > 0$, but not on $[0, \infty)$. I do understand the exercise and was able to solve it. I should take home, that the existence of multiple solution is possible, since the Lipschitz-condition in the Picard-Lindelöf theorem is not fulfilled.

**Question:** Let's look over the fact that $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous in $0$. How would I apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem for an IVP, where $f$ is only defined for $t \geq t_0$, since I can't define a cylinder $D$ as in the theorem?

Comment: What are you to give to the different solutions, and how do you do it?

Comment: More seriously, could you add the point where you apply Picard-Lindelöf to your problem? Nobody prevents you to get more from the theorem and restrict the result afterwards to match your task.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry, I don't quite understand your first comment. I was asked to give two different solutions and found $u(t) = 0$ and $u(t) = (\frac{3}{4}t)^\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: @LutzL I afterwards was asked to show that I that $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous in $0$ and why that matters. I explained, that it matters since I think otherwise two different solutions would violate Picard-Lindelöf. But would it violate Picard-Lindelöf? We couldn't apply it anyway since we cannot build a cylinder $D$ as in the definition, right?

Comment: Read again what you wrote. // You can always extend the domain, here for instance by considering $u'=|u|^{1/4}$ or $u'=\max(0,u)^{1/4}$. These are as regular as the original equation. As an autonomous equation, there are no restrictions in time. But the point is, that for any $u_0 >0$ you can always consider a cylinder $\{(t,u):|u-u_0|<u_0/2\}$ to get local uniqueness. There is no branching in the region $u>0$, it only happens at $u=0$.